# Network Accounts take extremely long to show up on Mac OS Ventura

Tags: mac

We have Active Directory and our Mac users log in using the "Other" option to log into their AD Account. However, the option to log into their AD account takes an extremely long time to populate (10-20 minutes). Why does this happen? Is there any way to fix it?